# Custom Comparison at the object

Tags: c#, .net

This question is NOT about passing a Comparison to a Sort.

The question is how to pass a Comparison to an object for object to object  (1:1) Comparison.   Some users must be able to pass in a Comparison.  They want 2 as want be able to tell when they give different comparison.

The way this solution approaches it is to pass a Comparison delegate to the constructor.

```
static int CompareMotorPrice(Motorcycle motorcycle1, Motorcycle motorcycle2)
{
    return motorcycle1.Price.CompareTo(motorcycle2.Price);
}
static int CompareMotorSpeed(Motorcycle motorcycle1, Motorcycle motorcycle2)
{
    return motorcycle1.Speed.CompareTo(motorcycle2.Speed);
}
public class Motorcycle : IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public Comparison<Motorcycle> CompareDelegate { get; set; }
    public Comparison<Motorcycle> CompareDefault { get; set; }
    public int CompareViaDelegate(Motorcycle motorcycle2)
    {
        if (CompareDelegate == null || motorcycle2 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        return (CompareDelegate(this, motorcycle2));
    }
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Motorcycle otherMotorcycle = obj as Motorcycle;
        if (otherMotorcycle != null)
        {
            if (CompareDefault == null)
            {
                return (this.Name.CompareTo(otherMotorcycle.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                return CompareDefault(this, otherMotorcycle);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a otherMotorcycle");
        }
    }
    public Motorcycle(string name, int price, int speed, Comparison<Motorcycle> compareDefault = null, Comparison<Motorcycle> compareDelegate = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Speed = speed;
        CompareDelegate = compareDelegate;
        CompareDefault = compareDefault;
    }
}
```

test:

```
Motorcycle motorcycle1 = new Motorcycle("harley", 1000, 120, CompareMotorSpeed, CompareMotorPrice);
Motorcycle motorcycle2 = new Motorcycle("yamaha", 1900, 130, CompareMotorSpeed, CompareMotorPrice);
Motorcycle motorcycle3 = new Motorcycle("susuki", 1800, 150, CompareMotorSpeed, CompareMotorPrice);
Debug.WriteLine(motorcycle1.CompareViaDelegate(motorcycle2));
List<Motorcycle> Motorcycles = new List<Motorcycle>() { motorcycle1, motorcycle2, motorcycle3 };
foreach (Motorcycle m in Motorcycles)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"name {m.Name}   price {m.Price}   speed {m.Speed}");
}
Motorcycles.Sort(CompareMotorPrice);
foreach (Motorcycle m in Motorcycles)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"name {m.Name}   price {m.Price}   speed {m.Speed}");
}
Motorcycles.Sort();
foreach (Motorcycle m in Motorcycles)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"name {m.Name}   price {m.Price}   speed {m.Speed}");
}
```

Comment: This is not very useful because that's exactly what the `IEqualityComparer<>` and `IComparable<>` interfaces are for. You are reinventing the wheel in a non-.net-compatible way.

Comment: @t3chb0t It does implement IComparable. I am sorry you do not see the value.

Comment: @paparazzo,  t3chb0t is talking about generic interfaces (`IComparable<Motorcycle>`). You do not implement those.

Comment: @NikitaB Not following.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @paparazzo There is another *generic* interface (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx), which does not require casting.

Comment: @NikitaB OK.  Comment from t3 was it did not implement  IComparable<>.

Comment: @paparazzo `Type<>` is sometimes used for referring to a type with a single type parameter (as per `typeof(Thing<>)`), `Type<,>` having 2 type params, `Type<,,>` having 3, etc. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

> ```
>     if (CompareDelegate == null || motorcycle2 == null)
>     {
>         throw new ArgumentNullException();
>     }
> ```

This exception is misleading. First, it does not specify which parameter is `null`. Second, strictly speaking `CompareDelegate` is not a parameter.

2) I would set the default value for `CompareDefault`:

```
public Comparison<Motorcycle> CompareDefault { get; set; } = 
    other => Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
```

this way you can probably remove some of the null checks and simplify `CompareTo` implementation.

3) Overall, I don't like this approach.

- it scales poorly.
- it hides comparison logic: there is no way to learn how two objects are going to be compared just by reading the code, the comparison logic is hidden inside some delegate.
- most importantly, you break *asymmetric property* of comparison. If `a.CompareTo(b) > 0` then I expect that `b.CompareTo(a) < 0`. But it is not the case, since nothing in your code prevents two objects from using different delegates for comparison. This alone looks like a huge source of problems to me.

IMHO, just write a bunch of regular `IComparer<T>` implementations and be done with it. It has none of the problems I mentioned above:

```
//custom comparers are implemented as stand alone classes, 
//they are not part of Motorcycle class.
public class Motorcycle
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public Motorcycle(string name, int price, int speed)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Speed = speed;
    }
}

//It also guarantees asymmetry:
//if SpeedComparer.Compare(a,b) < 0 then SpeedComparer.Compare(b,a) > 0 is also true
class SpeedComparer : IComparer<Motorcycle>
{
    public int Compare(Motorcycle first, Motorcycle second)
    {
        //add null checks

        return first.Price.CompareTo(second.Price);
    }
}

class NameComparer : IComparer<Motorcycle>
{
    public int Compare(Motorcycle first, Motorcycle second)
    {
        //add null checks

        return first.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void Test()
{
    var motorcycle1 = new Motorcycle("harley", 1000, 120);
    var motorcycle2 = new Motorcycle("yamaha", 1900, 130);
    var motorcycle3 = new Motorcycle("susuki", 1800, 150);
    var motorcycles = new List<Motorcycle>() { motorcycle1, motorcycle2, motorcycle3 };

    IComparer<Motorcycle> selectedComparer = new NameComparer();
    //compares by name
    TestComparison();

    selectedComparer = new SpeedComparer();
    //selectedComparer is changed, so now speeds are compared
    TestComparison();

    void TestComparison()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Using {selectedComparer.GetType().Name}...");
        Debug.WriteLine(selectedComparer.Compare(motorcycle1, motorcycle2));
        motorcycles.Sort(selectedComparer);
        motorcycles.ForEach(m => Debug.WriteLine($"name {m.Name}   price {m.Price}   speed {m.Speed}"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. MotorcCycle not know Comparison is what I need to do.  I need to change out Comparison external.  Users want to able to change out  Comparison on the fly.  Think designing a scoring criteria.  And they also want to know when two Comparison do not give the same results.

Comment: I get not symmetric is a potential problem.  Here is my question.  How do you pass an  IComparer to Compare.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx I am not seeing any overloaded method to pass an IComparer.  In the documentation it says this interface is used with the List<T>.Sort and List<T>.BinarySearch methods.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @paparazzo `Users want to able to change out Comparison on the fly` -  this scenario is usually handled by swapping `IComparer<T>` implementation. You don't have to pass comparer to `Compare` method, you should call`IComparer<T>.Compare()` directly. Basically, instead of `a.CompareTo(b)` and `list.Sort()`, you should call `userSelectedComparer.Compare(a, b)` and `list.Sort(userSelectedComparer)` respectively (where `userSelectedComparer` is `IComparer<T>` field, that user can change via UI somehow).

Comment: Not sure I follow but I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your time but I don't see how this can stop a and b from having different userSelectedComparer in the case of a.CompareTo(b).

Comment: @paparazzo It seems like you have misunderstood how comparers should be used, so  I've added a usage example.

Comment: I was stuck on passing it rather than use it directly.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Nikita the problem is a.CompareTo(b) might not by symmetric with b.CompareTo(a).  Some times users ask for stuff that just does not make sense.  A reality is often it is just easier to do it with limitations.

I think I have something that will work:

```
public delegate int DelegateDeclaration(Car car1, Car car2);
// implementation
public static int DelegateImplementation1(Car car1, Car car2)
{
    return car1.HP.CompareTo(car2.HP);
}
public class Car : IComparer<Car>
{
    public IComparer<Car> Comparer { get; set; }
    public int Compare(Car car1, Car car2)
    {
        if (car1 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("car1");
        }
        if (car1 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("car1");
        }
        if (Comparer == null)
        {
            return car1.Name.CompareTo(car2.Name);
        }
        return Comparer.Compare(car1, car2);  //dangerous as they might not have the same Comparer
    }
    public int ComareTo(Car other)
    {
        return Compare(this, other);
    }
    public bool CompareSame(Car other)
    {
        return Compare(this, other) == -Compare(other, this);
    }
    public int ComareTo(Car other, DelegateDeclaration dgate)
    {
        return dgate(this, other);
    }
    public bool ComareSame(Car other, DelegateDeclaration dgate1, DelegateDeclaration dgate2)
    {
        return dgate1(this, other) == dgate2(this, other);
    }
    public String Name { get; }
    public int HP { get; set; }
    public Car(string name, int hp, IComparer<Car> comparer = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        HP = hp;
    }
}
```